# How to extract many files from multiple 7z using Python?

Tags: python, 7zip

I need to extract 700k jpg files that are dispersed among 50 7z files. I have a txt file that has one row for each file I need. The row contains the target 7z file and location and file name.

This is what the txt file looks like:

```
A20000to22000.7z, A20000to22000/rows/A21673.Lo1sign.jpg
B20000to22000.7z, B20000to22000/rows/B21673.Lo1sign.jpg
```

I currently am able to extract files with Python but only from one 7z at a time. I use this command to do that:

```
7zz e A0000to22000.7z @f1.txt
```

This is taking way too long though. Is there anyway to edit the command or use another approach so I can extract many different files from many different 7z files at once?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: Do you mean that the `7zz` command itself is too slow or that it takes you too long to repeat that command for all `.7z` files manually?

Comment: You describe a text file - is that the same one you refer to as `f1.txt` in your command?

Comment: No. So the f1.txt file only contains a file location and name. It does not need the 7z target because I only know how to unzip based on a txt list from one 7z at a time. The command specifies the target.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it would take to long to repeat the command manually for all 50 7z files.

Comment: So your questions are (1) how you can start a command from Python and (2) how you can use a loop in Python? And/or (3) how you can read a file in Python and split each line into individual components?

Comment: My question can be found in the original post. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: mkrieger1 is trying to help you and just asking for a little clarification before investing his freely volunteered effort...

Comment: Do you want them all unzipped into one location? If so, is it possible you'll have naming collisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

With the new information that there are lots of files to retrieve from each archive, a modified approach is needed.

First we must generate a list of the files needed from each 7z archive, then process that list in parallel. So this code should do that:

```
awk -F, '{sub("7z","txt",$1); print $2 > $1}' joblist.txt
```

That should make a file called  `A20000to22000.txt` that contains all the files to be extracted from the archive `A20000to22000.7z` and similarly for `B20000to22000.7z` it should produce `B20000to22000.txt`.

Don't proceed past here till the files ending in `.txt` look correct.

Now we need to process the `.txt` files in parallel with **GNU Parallel**. That should look something like this:

```
parallel --dry-run 7zz e {.}.7z @{} ::: *to*.txt
```

I used `*to*.txt` in order to avoid processing the original `joblist.txt`.

If that command looks correct, remove `--dry-run` and run for real.

**Original Answer**

Assuming `joblist.txt` looks like this:

```
A20000to22000.7z, A20000to22000/rows/A21673.Lo1sign.jpg
B20000to22000.7z, B20000to22000/rows/B21673.Lo1sign.jpg
```

and that corresponds to needing to run a command like:

```
7zz e A20000to22000.7z A20000to22000/rows/A21673.Lo1sign.jpg
```

you can do that in parallel with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel --dry-run --colsep , 7zz e {1} {2} :::: joblist.txt
```

If it looks right, remove `--dry-run` and run for real.

---

Note that this is done in the terminal/shell and without Python, so it falls under the *"another approach"* you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. This does work, but it appears to uncompressed a 7z for each line. That is an issue because the files are 5gb or more.

Comment: If there are 50 lines in the file, it will do 50 decompressions - it *has* to, surely? Else how could it get all 50 files?

Comment: There is 50 total 7z file with over 700k target files I need to retrieve. So many files per 7z. The solution seems to decompress a 7z for each line which would take way way long.

Comment: Aha! That's a critical piece of information that should have been in the question. Can you click [edit] and update it to make that clear please? It's late here, so I'll rejig my solution tomorrow.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you check the `awk` command and see if it works ok please?

Comment: The updated solution works perfectly! Thank you so much. It just pulled 28k files out of two different 7z files very fast.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.